# How to run ANTS memory profiler from the command line

Tags: red-gate-ants

I'm trying to use ANTS memory profiler to monitor the memory consumption while i'm running automated test without luck.

I understand that ANTS Memory Profiler wants to be responsible for launching the application.  My approach was to create an ANTS memory profiler project that would call my app, and then set ants to autolaunch my app using the following:

"C:\Program Files\Red Gate\ANTS Memory Profiler 7\RedGate.MemoryProfiler.UI.exe" /nowizard /startimmediately

This come from the only command line docs i could find that is for version 4.  I'm running version 7 and these don't work

http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/ANTS_Profiler/help/4.0/AP_startup_parameters

if I try running RedGate.MemoryProfiler.UI.exe /help from the command line I just get the app launching.  is command line support still in this product?

I'm also exploring regular support channels but was hoping someone here might know.

Answer (score 1):

no, CL is not suported anymore for the Memory Profiler. Instead, we have an API:

https://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.4/amp_snapshot_api

Call RedGate.MemoryProfiler.Snapshot.TakeSnapshot() whenever you want to take a snapshot.

Comment: thanks for the link to the API, unfortunately I still need to launch the ANTS Memory Profiler app to make this work.  I'm launching my app from an automated test tool, so the API does not help in my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this myself but I wonder of simply leaving ANTS running will work (at least for one test run)